# "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Component.router')" when running a boiler plate react-navigation app

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-component

I am new to react-native and wanted to try out react-navigation. 
But when I try to run a basic app it gives me 'undefined is not an object(evaluating 'Component.router)' error. Please help

here's a screenshot of the error
https://i.gyazo.com/fa89defeff8bef894f509f1511f9b1ae.png

Here's the only thing I changed in the default project except for installing 
react-navigation and react-native-gesture-handler

````
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer,
        createSwitchNavigator,
        createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return <AppNavigator/>;
  }
}

class MainScreen extends Component{
  render(){
    return <Text>Hi</Text>
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  MainScreen : MainScreen,

});```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues in your code

(1) You are trying to access `SwitchNavigator` before it's declaration.
(2) You are doing `MainScreen : MainScreen`, which will cause an error.

```
const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  MainScreen,
});
```

or

```
// optionally pass an object to your route, with screen, navigation options
const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  MainScreen: { screen: MainScreen },
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. 
This solved my problem. I was using the variable before declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are accessing SwitchNavigator **before** its declaration.

**let** and **const** variables can be accessed only **after** their declarations.

Example:

```
console.log(a); // Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization
const a = 10;
```

source: [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init)

That being said, your code should be:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer,
        createSwitchNavigator,
        createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return <AppNavigator/>;
  }
}

class MainScreen extends Component{
  render(){
    return <Text>Hi</Text>
  }
}

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  MainScreen : MainScreen,
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);
```

Answer (score 0):

seems ok except you forgot to import MainScreen

```
import { MainScreen } from '..pathname'
```